# Python Word Vect numpy array, on saving to csv gave error on dimension , Expected 1D or 2D array, got 0D array instead

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, countvectorizer

Saving wordVect gave error,

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
corpus = [
    'This is the first document.',
    'This document is the second document.',
    'And this is the third one.',
    'Is this the first document?',
]
vectorizer = CountVectorizer(ngram_range=()
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)

# Save The Vector 
np.savetxt('logvect.csv', X, delimiter=',')
```

Got Error

**----> 1 np.savetxt('logvect.csv', X, delimiter=',')**

```
   1375         if X.ndim == 0 or X.ndim > 2:
   1376             raise ValueError(
-> 1377                 "Expected 1D or 2D array, got %dD array instead" % X.ndim)
   1378         elif X.ndim == 1:
   1379             # Common case -- 1d array of numbers

ValueError: Expected 1D or 2D array, got 0D array instead
```

Comment: The first thing `savetxt` does is `x = np.asarray(x)`, that is try to turn the input into a numpy array (if it isn't already).  What does `np.asarray(X)` do to your `X`?

Comment: Sorry What ? x = np.asarray(x) .. Where .. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

X.toarray() # Was missing

```
np.savetxt('logvect.csv', X.toarray(), delimiter=',')
```